# Why is Groovy metaClass .static changes using MOP not behaving as expected

Tags: groovy, properties, static, metaclass

I have set up a simple dummy class as follows, and used a static initialiser to update the metaClass:

```
class DynamicExtendableClass {

    static String declaredStaticString = "declared static string"

    static String getDeclaredMethodStaticString () {
        "static method returning string"
    }

        static {
            println "static initialiser - adding dynamic properties and methods to metaClass"
            DynamicExtendableClass.metaClass.addedProperty = "added property to class metaClass"
            DynamicExtendableClass.metaClass.getAddedMethod = { -> "added closure as method" }
            DynamicExtendableClass.metaClass.static.getStaticAddedMethod = { -> "added closure as static method" }

        }
}
```

I have a simple test case like this:

```
@Test
void testExtendedMetaClassStuff () {

    DynamicExtendableClass testInstance = new DynamicExtendableClass()

    assertEquals ("added property to class metaClass", testInstance.addedProperty)
    assertEquals ("added closure as static method", testInstance.getStaticAddedMethod())  //calls getStaticAddedMethod - groovy trick
    assertEquals ("added closure as method", testInstance.addedMethod)  //works.  calls getAddedMethod - groovy trick for getXxx as property
    assertEquals ("added closure as static method", DynamicExtendableClass.staticAddedMethod )  //works class static class Closure

}
```

Which works only once you create a first instance of the class which forces a switch to ExpandoMetaClass for you.

If you don't  do this first the default HandleMetaClassImpl doesn't work for this.

However to get this to work for static you have to create closure like getXxxx = {-> ...}, which if you call 'DynamicExtendableClass.staticAddedMethod' will sneakily invoke the closure for you.

However, there's **not** really a means to add a **property** capability here for '.static' as there is on the standard metaClass itself. All you can do is set a **closure** onto .static.  Why is this?

The other problem is having to create an instance of the class first to force the switch to ExpandoMetaClass, is there not a simple way to force the metaClass change when declaring the class in the first class, before creating any instances ?

I want to add some static properties (later some methods maybe ) dynamically to a class, but all you can add is static closures, which is a little limiting on the scenario I had in mind.

---

### PostScript

I managed to force a change of metaClass on class without having to create an instance, but it's a bit hard work:

```
@Test
void testMetaClassStatic () {

    println DynamicExtendableClass.metaClass
    
    MetaClassRegistry registry = GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry()
    MetaClass origMC = registry.getMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass)
    assert origMC.getClass() == HandleMetaClass  //default implementation 

    ExpandoMetaClass emc = new ExpandoMetaClass (DynamicExtendableClass, true, true)
    emc.static.getStaticAddedMethod = {-> "static hello from my emc"}
    emc.initialize()

    registry.removeMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass)
    registry.setMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass, emc)

    assert DynamicExtendableClass.metaClass.getClass() == ExpandoMetaClass

    assert DynamicExtendableClass.staticAddedMethod == "static hello from my emc"

    registry.removeMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass)
    registry.setMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass, origMC)

}
```

But doing this breaks my previously working tests (not sure why) with:

```
Could not initialize class extensible.DynamicExtendableClass
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class extensible.DynamicExtendableClass
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:268)
    at extensible.DynamicExtendableClassTest.testExtendedMetaClassStuff(DynamicExtendableClassTest.groovy:22)
    at ...
```

---

### Another postscript

I did a little exploration with a debugger. 1st the metaClass.static returns a class of type ExpandoMetaClass.ExpandoMetaProperty which of itself isn't terribly useful.  You can do a direct .@this$0 field access however which just points the same metaClass instance as the target class you start with.

Therefore ignoring this you can do a direct field grab on `<yourClass>.metaClass.@expandoProperties` (I tried to get this via reflection using:

```
PropertyValue expandoProperties = clazz.metaClass.getMetaPropertyValues().find{it.name == 'expandoProperties'}
List<MetaBeanProperty> MBprops2= properties.getValue()
Map m2 = MBprops.findAll{Modifier.isPublic(it.modifiers)}.collectEntries{[(it.name), it.getProperty(clazz)] }
```

but it doesn't  get the same content as the direct field access does.
The direct field access returns a Map where the key is the string value of any added closures or properties added dynamically to the metaClass, and the value is a MetaBeanProperty reference.

On that MetaBeanProperty you can invoke the `getProperty (object)` using with the class metaClass or per instance metaClass - and it returns the value of that property (whether it's just a closure or a real property) for you.  You can also test whether its static or not:

```
    Map m4 = thisMc.@expandoProperties
    MetaBeanProperty asm = m4['addedStaticMethod']
    def val2 = asm.getProperty(clazz)
    boolean isstatic = Modifier.isStatic(asm.modifiers)
```

Kind of brutal but it sort of works if you want to dynamically query the dynamic editions to the metaclass.

The problem of forcing the switch from default metaClass to the ExpandoMetaClass remains a problem.  The best way seems to create a throw away class instance as this does the one time switch for you.

I tried to force this myself using the metaClass registry which you can do, but then the future create new instance for your class seems to stop working  ie. doing somethings like this and putting the original back afterwords seems to break any future new `<MyClass>()` calls.

```
       MetaClassRegistry registry = GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry()
        MetaClass origMC = registry.getMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass)
        assert origMC.getClass() == MetaClassImpl  //default implementation

        def  constructors = MetaClassImpl.getConstructors()

        ExpandoMetaClass emc = new ExpandoMetaClass (DynamicExtendableClass, true, true)
        emc.static.getStaticAddedMethod = {-> "static hello from my emc"}

        emc.constructor = { new DynamicExtendableClass() }
      emc.initialize()

        registry.removeMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass)
        registry.setMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass, emc)

        assert DynamicExtendableClass.metaClass.getClass() == ExpandoMetaClass

        assert DynamicExtendableClass.staticAddedMethod == "static hello from my emc"

         registry.removeMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass)
        registry.setMetaClass(DynamicExtendableClass, origMC)
```

Comment: There is a lot of information in the question.  Is one of your questions how to add a static property to class at runtime that doesn't require creating an instance of the class prior to accessing?

Comment: hi jeff - its not the adding you can do that my MyClass.metaClass.static.getClos = {"some val"}.   however you can only add closure property via classic.  If you try and do MyClass.metaClass.static = "some val" - groovy lets you add a static property but  you cant get that property and look at it (like you can do when you add a basic property dynamically.

Comment: there is a `myc.metaClass.getStaticMetaMethod()` function - but nothing for `getStaticMetaProperty()`.  the only way to simulate a static property is to add a closure to `metaClass.static.getXyz = {-> "result"}` .  you cant get a list of these you have to know the name of the closure you added to query for it and get its value

Comment: the handling for `metaClass.static` is different than for just adding non static methods and properties directly to a metaClass

Comment: "groovy lets you add a static property but you cant get that property and look at it (like you can do when you add a basic property dynamically." - that isn't true.  We do that routinely in Grails.

Comment: The technique you are using doesn't work, but that doesn't mean Groovy doesn't support it.  Is one of your questions how to add a static property to class at runtime that can be accessed like a normal property and doesn't require creating an instance of the class prior to accessing?

Comment: What i wanted to do was 1) add a new static property to metaClass ( but you only seem to be able to create a new closure to static and be able to call that, if you add a property to metaClass.static groovy lets you do that but i then cant access it)

Comment: 2) I want to be able to query a metaclass for getsStaticMetaMethods() and getStaticProperties() - but these don't seem to exist in the MetaClass interface spec

Comment: basically i was expecting symmetric behaviour for metaClass.static as you would with ordinary properties and methods.  but that doesnt seem to exist in the MOP interface spec.  Why isn't the behaviour the same for static meth/props as for ordinary.  Where in grails code tree are they accessing static properties from metaClass.static?

Comment: as far as i can see grailsClassUtils has a method `public static Object getStaticPropertyValue(Class<?> clazz, String name)` that uses springs `BeanUtils.findDeclaredMethod` which itself uses reflection returning `clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramTypes)`.  So this doesnt let you query for static methods/properties on the metaClass.static property.  When i looked at the type for metaClass.static in the debugger it looked like a reference to metaClass again.  I can't quite figure out how metaClass.static really works

Comment: "add a new static property to metaClass ( but you only seem to be able to create a new closure to static and be able to call that"- That is a surprising requirement.  If you could do it without a Closure, would that satisfy your needs?

Comment: I saw your comment that my answer did not address your question.  I am sorry that I misunderstood.  I have deleted my answer.

Comment: Jeff the query is about (lack of ) symmetric capability around the metaClass i think.  I have to work with what i can do, but the observation is that you can add dynmaic properties and methods to metaClass and there are methods to support querying these.  There is a .static property.  You can add a property or method (as closure) to .static and groovy quietly accepts both.  however there is only getStaticMetaMethod(name) you can call.

Comment: "Jeff the query is about (lack of ) symmetric capability around the metaClass i think." - Please feel free to submit an enhancement request including a description of the lack of capability and desired behavior.  Information at https://groovy.apache.org/ provides some direction.  Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: there are no getStaticMethods or getStaticProperties() calls on metaClass to mirror that of ordinary properties and methods.  I cant figure out the .static is doing but if you add stuff you then cant find/process it readily (other than getStaticmetaMethod (name) - so you have to know the name in advance )

Comment: its this asymmetry thats bother me.  and the first change from metaClassImpl and ExpandoMetaClass.  it just seems half complete.  I've had to work around this and approach my initial problem in another way and avoid using adding stuff to metaClass.static

Comment: Hi jeff i raised the jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-10392 and marked as minor.  Its annoying and incomplete but there are other ways to do stuff.  I hope it might get a fix at some point